# After upgrading to iPhone OS 4 my TableView scrolls to top after reloadData called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that needs to be updated after a notification is posted.  I do this by calling reloadData on the TableView.  Before I upgraded to OS 4 the tableView would maintain its vertical scroll position.  After upgrading to 4.0 it scrolls to the top after reloadData is called.   Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

"Bad" solution is after reloadData to scroll to a target row (with scrollToRowAtIndexPath:..., for example) by timer with time interval that's proportional to new data loading time. But this is the bad solution :)